# Foreign key with entity framework code first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, ef-code-first, cascade

I have read the many question for Foreign key issue with EF on stackoverflow and their suggested solution. But none worked for my case.

I have a parent class XSection

```
public class XSection
{
  public int ObjectId {get; set;}
  public OverBank LeftOverBank {get; set;}
  public OverBank RightOverBank {get; set;}
}
```

The overbanks are the child entity (only one not the list) of the parent Xsection class. The OverBanks class looks likes

```
public class OverBank
{
  public int ObjectId {get; set;}
  public int ParentId (get; set;}

  public double Station {get; set;}
  // some other basic properties 
}
```

The DDL generated for the above classes are:

**CrossSection table**:

```
CREATE TABLE CrossSection ( 
  ObjectID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  LeftOverbank_ObjectID INTEGER NULL,
  RightOverbank_ObjectID INTEGER NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ObjectID),
  FOREIGN KEY (LeftOverbank_ObjectID) REFERENCES Overbank (ObjectID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (RightOverbank_ObjectID) REFERENCES Overbank (ObjectID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
);

CREATE INDEX IX_FK_CrossSection_LeftOverbank ON CrossSection (LeftOverbank_ObjectID);

CREATE INDEX IX_FK_CrossSection_RightOverbank ON CrossSection (RightOverbank_ObjectID);
```

**OverBank table**

```
CREATE TABLE Overbank ( 
  ObjectID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Station real NULL,
  DisplayLabel text NULL,
  Description text NULL,
  Name text NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ObjectID),

);
```

To enable cascade delete I wrote the following on OnModelCreating event:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity <CrossSection>()
              .ToTable("CrossSection");
     modelBuilder.Entity <Overbank>()
              .ToTable("Overbank");

    modelBuilder.Entity<CrossSection>().HasOptional(xs => xs.LeftOverbank).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    modelBuilder.Entity<CrossSection>().HasOptional(xs => xs.RightOverbank).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

We can see the foreign key constraints are reversed. Also when I delete the crosssection associated overbank doesn't get delete, whereas when I delete the overbank associated cross-section gets deleted. Whereas we require the just opposite of what we have now. Is there something very silly.

Comment: Is that all of the mapping configuration you wrote? Or is there more?

Comment: I have edited the full OnModelCreating event.

Answer (score 1):

Each of those Overbank properties is actually a 0..1:1 relationship. That's "zero or one to one". Instead of `WithMany()`, try `WithRequiredPrincipal()`.

Comment: Oh I got it I changed the same to modelBuilder.Entity<CrossSection>().HasOptional<Overbank>(xs => xs.LeftOverbank).WithOptionalPrincipal().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);. Now relationships are building correctly but cascade delete is not setting to true.

Comment: Likely because this model can't really comply with Entity Framework conventions. EF requires that tables in a 1:1 and 0..1:1 relationship have the same primary key, with the principle table generating the identity and the dependent table not having an identity column. But that convention would make it impossible to have a double 0..1:1 relationship. Let me pull back and ask a broader question. If Overbank is just a double (which probably should be a decimal unless you know it needs to be a float) and the relationship is 0..1:1 with cascade delete then why have them in a separate table at all?

Comment: There are other properties also that I have not mentioned to keep the example simple. Also when I manually updates the CASCADE delete option using dbEditor everything works fine.